# PLSQL Invalid Month

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why am I getting invalid month when I test this code? How does PLSQL and XML handle data types?

```
CURSOR c_DATA_INF is 
  select * from xmltable ('/' PASSING i_XML COLUMNS READING_DT DATE PATH 'DATE',
                          Actual NUMBER PATH 'ACTUAL',
                          Eligible NUMBER PATH 'ELIGIBLE'
                         );
              begin
                for d in c_DATA_INF loop                  
                  insert into table_name(READING_DT, actual, eligible) 
                  values (to_date('d.READING_DT', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), d.ACTUAL, d.ELIGIBLE);
                end loop;
              end;
```

I'm not sure if it's incorrect in my insert statement or in my cursor.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you show an example of dates stored in XML ?

Comment: They are stored as 06/28/2016.  <DATE>06/28/2016</DATE>

Comment: Declare the column as `varchar2(10)`, not a `DATE` here: `COLUMNS READING_DT  DATE PATH 'DATE'` - that is, use `COLUMNS READING_DT  VARCHAR(10) PATH 'DATE'` instead of previous declaration.

Comment: @kordirko Got rid of the invalid month error but  now I'm getting this error....ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected. Suggestions?

Comment: XML probably contains some records with non-numeric data in of these three fields, just create an ad-hoc query (copy-and-paste your `select * .....`), change their datatypes to `Varchar(4000)`, then check whether some records contains non numeric characters in these fields - `WHERE regexp_like( actual, '[^0-9]' )  OR regexp_like( reading_dt, '[^0-9/]' ) OR ....`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing d.READING_DT as string. within quotes. Please remove the quotes and try

Answer (score 0):

The parameter types are invalid in to_date(DATE, "DATE FORMAT STRING");

[Link to Example](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Instead of passing 'd.READING_DT', remove the quotes. Pass: d.READING_DT

The error is thrown becasue Oracle does not recognize 'd.READING_DT' as a valid date/ or date string.